# PHP Mongodb как получить meta данные файла?

Tags: php, mongodb

Значит разобрался с хранением файлов в базе монго
Сохраняю так

```
<?
$mongo = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
$db = $mongo->selectDB('myfiles');
$grid = $db->getGridFS();
$filename = "imany_never.mp3";
$filename = "video.mp4";
$mineType = "video/mp4";
// Сохраняю файл в базу с доп параметрами!
$storedfile = $grid->storeFile($filename, array("filename" => $filename, "fileSize" => filesize($path . $filename), "mineType" => $mineType));
```

Достаю так

```
<?
$image = $gridFS->findOne($filename);
echo $image->get('mineType'). PHP_EOL; // Тут пытаюсь получить МИМЕтип файла
echo $image->fileSize. PHP_EOL;   // так тоже не получается...
```

При сохранении я даю ему дополнительные meta данные тип, размер, миме, потом еще сделаю категорию, теги
Вот как это все получить при чтении???????

Answer (score 1):

Во первых надо это `<?` заменить на `<?php` это. Во вторых сделать так `var_dump($image->toArray()` найти где там записанно всё что вы хотите и записываетет и  вытащить методом `get()`

Comment: ДАК я так и делал)
ВОТ строка 
echo $image->get('mineType'). PHP_EOL; // ошибка выходит!

Comment: ВОТ пример http://prntscr.com/c1hzkp
ошибка
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method MongoGridFSFile::get() in readfile.php on line 36

Comment: @АлексЛизенберг а так `->mineType' ?

Comment: Ну емае)) в вопросе же все написано, и так и эдак пробовал!
Undefined property: MongoGridFSFile::$mineType
Вот смотри http://prntscr.com/c1mkrv это какие методы вообще есть
и распечатка самого объекта - там есть эти данные.... не могу понять как их достать

Comment: `var_dump($image)` что выводит полностью?

Comment: все норм разобрался, надо так $image->file['fileSize']
вот этот файл (file) и отвечает за работу именно с файлом